# Word - Using Figures - Anchor to Text but have figure show up *after* the text

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing up my thesis and taking a crash course in learning to use a lot of features of Word I didn't know existed. I have some requirements for figures for my thesis that I am trying to fulfill.

- **Insert figure and add the caption which are tethered together** (so far have either been grouping them or "stay with next")
- **Come after the cross-reference in the text** (ie. it must show up *after* the first mention in-text)
- **Stay at the top of the next page following the in-text mention**
- **Not do the annoying** "leaves huge blank space because it's anchored to the text but is on the next page" deal

This seems to be impossible? Yes, there is the solution of writing everything, THEN adding the figures and putting them in after final changes. But sending it out for revisions means that other people are touching the document and they *inevitably* mess up my formatting (and then complain about it and say I have to fix it). I'm hoping for a bulletproof method of dealing with these figures so they always do the things listed above. I thought this style was fairly standard, but I can't find anything about making sure these things show up after the in-text mention and be told to stay at the top of a page (or bottom, but top is preferred). You can either anchor the text OR have it stay in one place on a page (and when I try to get both to work, you get half-blank pages).

FWIW, I am using whatever the most recent Word version is.

Comment: I know your pain - and that's mostly why I have chosen Latex on my master's degree years ago. I don't have the answer to your question, but I'd suggest you to save as PDF and send it to revision - they will not be able to change the formatting, but they will be able to add notes there.

Comment: This kind of "finicky" work is best done at the end. The putting it on the next page just is not going to be automatic. Here is my writing on keeping captions with figures: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#MovingFigureCaption It sounds like what you are doing already. I would say, for now, let the figures and captions be together and after the first mention but do not worry about putting on the following page. Fix it in the final draft.